# Callback from ViewModel to View

Tags: c#, view, model, callback, action

My View calls a method in ViewModel to Fetch Data. After fetching the data, I build my View(Grid) based on the data that got back from the ViewModel.

getData() Method in the View Model runs in a BackgroundWorker thread. Now my question is how do I get back to View after the View is done fetching all the data?

```
    ViewModel
    {
       getData()
       {
            WorkerMethods()
            WorkerCompletedMethod()
            {
               Refresh()
            }
       }


       Refresh()
       {
           WorkerMethod()
           WorkerCompleted()
           {
                 data - Retrieved.
                 This is where all the calls are really DONE
           }
       }

     }
```

From the View, I will be calling

```
View()
{
     VM.getData()
     //Before I call this method, I want to make sure Refresh() is completed
     BuildUI()
}
```

I want the BuildUI() method to be executed only after the VM.getData() is executed fully and in turn is done with Refresh() method as well which is what has the Data I need to be able to build the UI Dynamically.

---

This is what I am going to do. Please correct me if this is not right approach.

In the View code behind,

```
  View
  {

      public delegate void DelegateRefresh();
      Init()
      {
          DelegateRefresh fetcher = RefreshData;
          fetcher.BeginInvoke(null, null);
      }


      public void RefreshData()
      {
        _viewModel.GetData();
        **while (_viewModel.IsBusy)**
        {               
            continue;
        }
        BuildUI();
      }

      BuildUI()
      {
         //Code to build the UI Dynamically using the data from VM.
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should retrieve the data once the `BackgroundWorker` has completed its work. Your view model should implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface and expose the data through a property that the view binds to. The view model can then notify the view when the data is available (i.e. the `BackgroundWorker` has completed its work).

Comment: You need to be clear and specific about what you are asking, otherwise you won't get helpful answers. Please update your question.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my oroginal Post, please let me know if its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use messaging. That is, register your message on the view, then send a message from the view model to the view, when this message is received then you could call your `BuildUI` method.

For example, if you were using the MvvmLight framework, here's one way of passing back an error message to show up in a dialog. You might not want to show a dialog (I had this code on hand), but the process is the same, it's just a different message type to register and send.

ViewModel:

```
public class ErrorMessage : DialogMessage
{
    // See MvvmLight docs for more details, I've omitted constructor(s)

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the specified recipient.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="recipient">The recipient of the message.</param>
    /// <param name="action">The action to perform when a message is sent.</param>
    public static void Register(object recipient, Action<ErrorMessage> action)
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<ErrorMessage>(recipient, action);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends error dialog message to all registered recipients.
    /// </summary>
    public void Send()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send<ErrorMessage>(this);
    }
 }

public class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public void SendErrorMessage(string message)
    {
        var errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(message);
        errorMessage.Send(); 
        // Or in your case, when the background worker is completed.          
    }
}
```

View:

```
public partial class SomeView : Window
{
     public SomeView()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        ErrorMessage.Register(this, msg =>
        {
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(msg.Content, msg.Caption,
                msg.Button, msg.Icon, msg.DefaultResult, msg.Options);
            msg.ProcessCallback(result);
            // Or in your case, invoke BuildUI() method.
        });
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am not using  MvvmLight framework though. We are using PRISM. Anyway, this is what I ended up doing.  I have created a delegate method and called BeginInvoke() on it. Inside the delegate method, I will be checking for a IsBusy Property in ViewModel to be true, once its false, I know that I am done with my work in View Model. Will post the code in the Original post.

Comment: That will work fine. I do similar for mouse cursor using `IsWaiting` properly and converter.